# Puppeteer Sharp submit form

Tags: c#, puppeteer, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to convert node.js code to C# and I am stuck at this point. I need to submit the form but I could not find any method in c#.

```
 await page.$eval('#my-form', form => form.submit()),
```

I could not find any function for `$eval` in C#. I have tried `EvaluateExpressionAsync` in C# but it seems like it executes our script inside the page. I do not want to trigger a click event on the button. I just want to translate that line of code in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In puppeteer sharp that's being solved using extension methods.

```
await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#my-form")
    .EvaluateFunctionAsync("form => form.submit()");
```